# What is this kanji ? Looks like 七 three times

Tags: kanji, handwriting

Tonight I went to a sushi restaurant. It's called かね喜{き} as is visible on their inkan and in the company name.

However, on their [website](http://sushi-kaneki.co.jp/) it seems calligraphied differently but maybe I am just bad at identifying handwriting.

Even more strange is the sign there that does not look like 喜 at all. According to the website it seems to be the way the sushi bar of the chain are called, but that does not help with why it is written this way.

[image: Sushi sign with weird kanji]

Can anyone help me ? I have looked around in my phone (Aedict) on on Weblio, to no avail.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is the [草書体]{そうしょたい} (= "cursive script") for the kanji 「喜」, meaning "happiness", "delight", etc.

http://image.search.yahoo.co.jp/search?rkf=2&ei=UTF-8&p=%E5%96%9C+%E8%8D%89%E6%9B%B8%E4%BD%93

This is the reason that one's 77th birthday is called 「[喜寿]{きじゅ}」.

More technically speaking, though, it is the "re-block-ized" and stylized form of the original cursive script for 「喜」.  The original cursive is shown at top left of the web page above.

Answer (score 2):

㐂 U+3402 is indeed a non-standard form of 喜 U+559C and is graphically made of 七 U+4E03 three times.

[image]